# Why is Libreoffice using only one core?

Tags: libreoffice, multi-core

When I use libreoffice calc for big table (around 100 000 lines), when I make operations on the filters, libreoffice freezes for some times while calculating, and i've seen in the CPU use that it's using only one CPU core at 100% of capacity, my CPU is a 10th generation i7 with 2x6 cores, why isn't libreoffice using more of them?

I only have the problem with libreoffice, for instance, virtualbox runs perfectly fine with the 4 cores assigned to it. (libreoffice does that even without any other applications launched at the same time)

I am on ubuntu 20.04, and have just reinstalled libreoffice to be sure that i have the latest version 6.4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that task of filtering runs in a single thread. If an application is not written to take advantage of more threads/cores, operating system cannot do anything to run it in parallel, and you can have as many cores as you can, but only one will be used. Operating system can run independent applications in parallel. Within application, the application must make sure to take advantage of parallel computing. Some tasks can be executed in parallel and some need to wait for a result from previous command, so they have to run sequentially, and there is no way to split in it pieces and run them in parallel. Operating system cannot know which parts of an application can be parallelized. That is application's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, I thought libreoffice was optimized for multithreading, but if it's not it's not a bug, thanks.